# Does Microsoft logger support logging to database?

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, serilog, ilogger

I'm implementing logging in my worker services console application. I want to log to the database and maybe other places.

Since everyone seems to be using Serilog, I installed the Serilog package and *Serilog.Sinks.MsSqlServer*. But I had a number of issues. For starters, I got a conflict between `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` and `Serilog.ILogger`. And when I disabled the microsoft references, I get an error that `ILogger` is not generic and doesn't support type arguments.

So I'm thinking I'd like to keep it simple and just use the Microsoft logger. But I'm finding very limited information about using the Microsoft logger to log to the database. I found the lengthy article [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0). But nowhere does this article talk about a database and doesn't contain the word *sinks*.

I'd have thought this is a common task. Can someone point me in the right direction to logging to the database with the Microsoft logger? Is this even supported?

Comment: Loggers should not log to the DB, because that's slow and will block.

Comment: @IanKemp: Then how are you supposed to log to the database?

Comment: [You don't, at least not directly.](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#no-asynchronous-logger-methods) But traditional (relational) databases are the wrong type of datastore for logs anyway, because they aren't optimised for efficiently querying massive amounts of variable text like the contents of logs messages. Log storage and analysis is one of the reasons that document database engines were developed.

Comment: @IanKemp: Thanks for the link. I'll look into it. Seems awfully useful though to have logs in a database where they can be queried, search and easily displayed online.

Comment: @IanKemp: BTW, isn't logging to a file also blocking?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft only provides the interfaces through Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and some very basic loggers.

But because it's an interface, you could use any third party implementation which fits your needs.

You don't specify your needs exactly, so I recommend you to look for a LoggingProvider at nuget.org or GitHub.

Comment: In fact, you _can_ use MS logging abstractions and Serilog implementations.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why Serilog defines it's own `ILogger` interface? That was causing the conflict I had. If it's just implementing the existing `ILogger`?

Comment: It is doing both. You can use _just_ Serilog - logging API and backing implementations _or_ use MS logging API and have it backed by either MS, Serilog or other compatible logging framework like NLog.

Comment: @Fildor: I can't tell if that comment was directed at me. My question is, if Serilog is implmenting `ILogger`, why does it need to define its own `ILogger'? I don't see anyway to use the Microsoft `ILogger` without duplicating it. And I'm couldn't use the Serilog ILogger because it doesn't allow type arguments.

Comment: Oh. It was indeed directed at you, sorry @JonathanWood ... Serilog's ILogger is a different one from Microsoft's interface. But if you already use the MS API throughout your code base, you can "redirect" the calls through the Serilog pipeline. There should be a documentation about that on the Serilog website if I remember correctly. _Should_ be a easy a adding a `UseSerilog()` in DI along with the nuget and adding a configuration for the sinks while removing the config for the Microsoft providers.